# Create an Asana task with External Data

Tags: javascript, asana, asana-connect

I am having trouble creating an asana task with external data.  I can create a task fine, but i can't figure out what the cocktail is to be able to use the "external" data that is mentioned in the documentation.

```
$.ajax({
   url : global.task.url,
   type: "post",
   data: {
    assignee: "my-email@hidden.com",
    name: "Test task",
    notes: "this is a note",
    projects: 123123123123,
    workspace: global.workspace,
    external: {
     "id": "test",
     "data": "12345099"
    }
   },
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "MY-TOKEN");
   }
 })
```

the above code results in a 500 bad request.

I have also tried sending external stringified, which results in the error "No matching route for request".

The code above works perfectly if i remove the "external" from data.

i will be the first to say i do not typically call APIs so i feel like i must be doing something silly.  any help appreciated!

UPDATE:

i was able to create a task by passing in external as:

```
'external.id' = "test",
'external.data' = "123123123"
```

however, i do not see the external data i generated, so there is still something going on.

UPDATE (2):

if i run the code below, i will get a 500 server error.
if i comment out the "external" piece in the data, the tasks adds correctly.

```
$.ajax({
 url : "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks",
 contentType: "application/json",
 type: "post",
 beforeSend: function (xhr){
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + settings.token);
 },
 data: JSON.stringify({
  data: {
   assignee: "my-email@hidden.com",
   name: "Test task",
   notes: "this is a note",
   projects: [5555555555555], //not the real one i am passing in
   external: {
    id: "testID",
    data: "some sweet data"
   },
   workspace: 555555555555 //not what i am really passing in
  }
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be you already created a record with the id `test`? The IDs are unique - they have to be, or you couldn't use it for access. Try a random ID or something? You can always `GET /tasks/external:test` and see if there's a task there.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but got a 404 not found returned. I don't think there is an external:test set up as i have yet to be able to get the call to execute, and the only place that external data can originate from is an app

Comment: Oh! I just figured it out: you were sending the data as POST (form-encoded) data, but with the structure you're sending it should be sent as JSON.

Comment: i tried sending this for external: 
   external:{"id":"testID","data":"some sweet data"}

got 500 error back =/

Comment: Right, but you need to tell $.ajax to send it as JSON - by default it's sending it form-encoded. I think you need to call JSON.stringify() on the data and send `contentType: 'application/json'` in the parameters to ajax, but I'm not a jQuery expert I'm afraid :-/

Comment: ok, i updated my ajax call as suggested and got some slightly different results. i had to stringify the whole data call and pass the project as an array, but the dang external data still didn't save!! this is driving me bonkers. i know it's something stupid. it's got to be something stupid.

Comment: Oooh, ooh! I think I know what it is! You need to pass something of the form: `contentType: 'application/json', data: JSON.stringify({ data: { assignee: ... }})` - in other words, you need to wrap the payload in a `data` property, stringify it, then pass *that* as the data parameter to the ajax call. And then it... should work?

Comment: it was not a fan of that one, it basically told me "uh you didn't actually pass us anything, we at least need the workspace". I think i had tried that as well at some point... it is so frustrating... why don't they post a "worst case scenario" in their documentation?

Comment: Make sure you're passing in `workspace` as an integer perhaps? I can't tell from here if `global.workspace` is the ID or an object representing the workspace.

I'm sorry this is so painful for you! I hope I can help resolve it :-(

Comment: I appreciate the help! I am pretty sure it is ok, because if i comment out the "external" piece that i pass in, the task adds perfectly. I updated the topic with the ajax call i am now making that is throwing a 500 error if i pass in external, and working fine if i don't pass external at all

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm going to see if I can reproduce this error, and thanks again for your patience.

Comment: I have an update! I remember you saying the external id needed to be unique, so I added a random id (for testing of course). Now I am able to create the task with the external data, and I can retrieve the task successfully with the tasks/external:12345 url, BUT i still do not see the external data i set being returned in the response at all.

I believe the 500 error i was experiencing was because of the external ID being the same on multiple create requests (i have run a lot of tests, apparently one of them worked to create it!).

Comment: That's great news! Currently external data has to be specifically requested using `?opt_fields=external.data,external.id` (for instance), but I suspect we will change this to make it visible by default when it's set.

Comment: ahaaa, I called with those params and there's my data, hooray!  Thank you soOOoo much!  I appreciate your patience, i don't API great yet.  

Might be nice to add something to the documentation to that effect, it passively says the external data will be in the payload with the task when you get the task.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're actually just going to change it to send the external data by default. Also we have an upcoming revamp of the documentation, so hopefully that will help with cases like this!

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had here was that I was passing in my external ID as an integer which kept returning a "Invalid Request" error from Asana. Once I converted it to a string the task creation with external data worked fine.